# Javascript arguments.sort() throw error sort is not a function

Tags: javascript

Just wondering why i got an error with the following simple JavaScript function

```
function highest(){ 
  return arguments.sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
}
highest(1, 1, 2, 3);
```

Error messsage : TypeError: arguments.sort is not a function.

I am confused as arguments it is an array (i thought). Please help and explain why. Many thanks

Comment: That's because `arguments` is not an array, take a look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/L6j2hjtf/). It's an [`Arguments Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), which only acts like an array. Same goes to many array-like objects returned by native functions such as [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), for example, which returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object.

Comment: *“I am confused as arguments it is an array.”* `arguments` is not an array. It has a length and indexed properties, but if you check `arguments instanceof Array`, you’ll notice that it’s `false` (and that `Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments) === '[object Arguments]'`). As such, it doesn’t have methods from `Array.prototype`, including `sort`.

Comment: o ok it's not array, i keep thought it was an array, cause i do arguments[0], arguments[1] . why do i get a negative.... but thanks this clear things up for me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `arguments` has no `sort` method. Be aware that `arguments` is not an `Array` object, it's an array-like [`Arguments` object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6).

However, you can use `Array.prototype.slice` to convert `arguments` to an array; and then you will be able to use `Array.prototype.sort`:

```
function highest(){ 
  return [].slice.call(arguments).sort(function(a,b){ 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
}
highest(1, 1, 2, 3); // [3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: In modern engines, you could also skip the conversion to an array, and just use Array.prototype.sort directly: `[].sort.call( arguments, function(a,b) { ...`

Comment: @Paulpro Personally I don't like altering an `Arguments` object, and I prefer using arrays than array-like objects. But true, `[].sort.call(arguments)` should also work (and according to IETester works even on IE5.5).

Comment: Thanks it was my bad as i keep thought it was an array, when i use arguments[0], arguments[1]. Things are clear now.

Comment: How would one go about sorting on a particular property from JSON array?

Answer (score 6):

*use spread syntax to convert arguments to a real Array:*

```
   function highest(...arguments){ 
      return arguments.sort(function(a,b){ 
        return b - a; 
      }); 
   }
   highest(1, 1, 2, 3);
```

Output: `(4) [3, 2, 1, 1]`

[image: Console]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is by declaring the arguments as an array.

```
var myArguments = [1, 1, 2, 3];
var sortedArguments = [];
```

Thus the highest() can be defined as;

```
function highest(myArguments)
{ 
  return myArguments.sort(function(a,b)
  { 
    return b - a; 
  }); 
}
sortedArguments = highest(myArguments);
```