# Javascript object sort works only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorting, object

My ajax call returns a javascript object that is **sometimes** sortable. Sometimes because it literally works sometimes and other times it does not. I do not know why. When it does not work I get this.

> Uncaught TypeError: cars.sort is not a function

I have specified the return dataType to always be json. `console.log(typeof cars)` **always** return `object` regardless of whether sort works. 
Since this is inside success statement, it is safe to assume that cars is loaded everytime therefore it is not an async issue. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28311228/4996722) and decided to try `[].sort.call(cars).sort(sort_timestamp)` but it does not work. I am truly lost to why `cars.sort` works sometimes and not always. `sort_timestamp` is a function that sorts by timestamp field of car object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (cars) {
        console.log(typeof cars); // prints the word 'object'
        cars.sort(sort_timestamp);

        // I tried these as well. They also only work sometimes
        // cars.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp - b.timestamp);
        // [].sort.call(cars).sort(sort_timestamp);
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(Array.isArray(cars))` show you? All arrays are objects, but not all objects are arrays. It would seem the server-side code returning your JSON doesn't always return an array - can you show the relevant part of that code?

Comment: Can you inspect with dev tools and go to network tab and see what is the `response` from your server when your ajax is called? At a moment when it does not work

Comment: @nnnnnn shows true when it works and false when it does not. How can this happen if the objects literally have not changed

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(cars))` and show us what the result is when it works and when it doesn't - they must be different, or you wouldn't be getting the behaviour you've described. Seems to me the problem is server-side.

Comment: @antoni when it does not work response is `{}`

Comment: @nnnnnn yes they are different, when it works it's the whole cars objects, when it does not it is `{}`, but my API path are the same and everything is the same and I am the only person playing with it right now so why would it be different? could it be server connection issue?

Comment: If the `success` handler is called that would mean that as far as the browser is concerned a successful request and response occurred *and* the response was in valid JSON format. So I don't see how this could be a connection issue, at least not between browser and server. Can you show the relevant server-side code?

Comment: @nnnnnn unfortunately i dont have access to the server side code

Comment: The problem comes from the server @kevin_b

Comment: If you can't control the server-side code then probably all you can do is add a test in your `success` handler to check that the result actually is an array, and if not either display an error message or retry the request.

Comment: Array.prototype.sort accepts a comparator function; use that for deterministic sorting

Comment: @nnnnnn just checked the server log, it is returning the right cars object

Comment: @naomik from my understanding Array.prototype.sort is just .sort(). And that is what I am doing here? I even tried converting it to array first by `[].sort.call(cars).sort(sort_timestamp)`;

Comment: That code doesn't convert it to an array, it lets you sort an array-like object, but in any case the tests discussed in previous comments show that when it doesn't work you have nothing but an empty object so then there's nothing to sort.

Comment: @nnnnnn if I specify `dataType: 'json',` then the return object is considred an array? a bit confused

Comment: Kevin if you specify `dataType: 'json'` then jQuery expects the server's response to be in JSON format, which could encode an array *or* a plain object, or nested arrays/objects. (By the time your `success` handler is called jQuery has parsed the JSON and just passes the resulting array or object.) Anyway, if you're saying the server log showed that the correct array was sent but your client-side `success` handler is called with an empty object, I can't explain that, sorry. I don't think I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` is a method of `Array []` and not `object {}`.

To solve your problem you have 2 options:

- Fix your back-end service to make sure always return an `Array` where you wanted the sort
- Convert the `Object` to `Array`

To safely check if a variable is an `Object` you cannot use `typeof` as it returns `object` for both `Array and Object` types

use: `Object.prototype.toString.call( THEVARIABLEYOUWANTTOBECHECKED )`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (cars) {
      // check if cars is an object
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(cars) == "[object Object]")
      {
        var result = [];
        var keys   = Object.keys(cars);
        // then convert to an array;
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
          var key = keys[i];
          result.push(cars[key]);
        }

        cars = result;

        // then sort
        cars.sort();
      }
    }
});
```

hope that helps

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `Array.isArray()`?

Comment: Of course it will not work if sorting works because if sorting works it returned an `Array` not an `Object`. `Array` has method of `sort` while an `Object` does not. To make sure it `WILL` always work you need to convert it to an `Array` to make use of `sort` _or_ make your own `sort` function that can sort objects

Comment: @masterpreenz I see what you are doing here, but `keys = Object.keys(cars) isn't actually ` getting the keys and results stays at [] after the operation

Comment: `Object.keys(cars)` only gets all first level properties of an object, it will far more simpler if you put what is inside `cars` as well. We are all assuming here as you did not specify